# Oracle SQL substring

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I'm hoping to get your help! I am trying to return the substring starting from the end between . and \

**Here is an example field**

\BsadasdaCL04\files25\1Year\TEST\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca

**I'd like to return**

5249013-07-25-18-96572

The number of characters between the last \ and . can vary

Oracle Version 19.2.1.247

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '([^\.]+)\.\S+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```regex
([^\.]+)  match and capture the file name (without backslash or dot)
\.        match final dot extension
\S+       followed by an extension having one or more non whitespace characters
$         end of the input
```

Comment: You were faster :) btw, probably it would be better to replace `\S` with `[^.]`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Maybe not, if the filename could have multiple dots in it.  It depends on what the actual inputs would be.

Comment: My point is not dots, but whitespaces in or after the file extention. Your regexp return the same in case of several dots

Comment: Try on `'\1\2\3\abc....d e f' ` and `'\1\2\3\abc....def' ` and `'\1\2\3\abc....' `  , `'\1\2\3\abc.' `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(field, '^.*\\([^.\\]+)[.].*$', '\1')
from (select '\BsadasdaCL04\files25\1Year\TEST\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca' as field from dual) t
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
Select
  Regexp_substr(str, '([^\]+)\.[^.]*$',1,1,null,1) s
From( select '\BsadasdaCL04\files25\1Year\TEST\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca' str from dual);
```

Comment: Please stop dropping endless comments under my answer.  You posted this 4 minutes after I posted, by the way.

Comment: Hm, ok ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I just wanted to help you understand the difference. And I haven't understood your point about the timing, since my first comment says you were first... Btw, I answered from my phone, so it's not so convenient and easy